# How can i use 'parallel' option in jenkins pipeline in the 'post' section?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I looked at many pipeline examples and how to write the post build section in a pipeline script. But never got my answer i was looking for.
I have 4 jobs - say Job A,B,C and D. I want job A to run first, and if successful it should trigger Job B,C,D in parallel. If Job A fails, it should trigger only Job B. Something like below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

stages {
    stage('Build_1') {
        steps {
            sh '''
               Build Job A
            '''
        }
    }

post {
    failure {
        sh '''
            Build Job B
        '''
    }
    success {
         sh '''
             Build Job B,C,D in parallel
         '''
    }
}
}
```

I tried using 'parallel' option in post section but it gave me errors. Is there a way to build Job B,C,D in parallel, in the post 'success' section?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The parallel keyword actually can work inside a post condition as long as it is encapsulated inside a script block, as the script blocks is just a fallback to the scripted pipeline which will allow you to run parallel execution step wherever you want.
The following should work fine:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build_1') {
            steps {
                //  Build Job A
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        failure {
            // run job B
            build job: 'Job-B'
        }
        success {
            script {
                // run jobs B, C, D in parallel 
                def jobs = ['Job-B', 'Job-C', 'Job-D']
                parallel jobs.collectEntries { job ->
                    ["Building ${job}" : {
                        build job: job
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example and specific parameters or configuration (for the `build` keyword) can be added to each job execution according to your needs.

Comment: Awesome! [Example in the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-list) was too convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quiet clear about this:

> Invalid step "parallel" used - not allowed in this context - The
>   parallel step can only be used as the only top-level step in a stages
>   step

The more restrictive declarative syntax does not allow the usage of parallel in thw post section at the moment.

If you don't want to switch to the [scripted syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline), another option that should work: Build the jobs B,C,D in parallel in a second stage and move the  the failure condition in the post section of your first stage. As a result job B,C,D will run if A is successful. If A is not successful only job B will run.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('one') {
            steps {
                // run job A
            }   
            post {
                failure {
                    // run job B
                }
            }
        }
        stage('two') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                     // run job B, C, D
                )

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it worked (Using parallel as an additional stage and use one failure block).. But the issue i have is:

Comment: @cad.sneha The issue is missing in your comment.