# Parallel execution inside the post step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building to 2 different environments in the same pipeline and I want to make the cleanup for both environments in parallel.

As I understood, parallel does not work inside the post step: [post step parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806231/how-can-i-use-parallel-option-in-jenkins-pipeline-in-the-post-section).

Any suggestions? Example of my code:

```
post {
    always {
        script{
            cleanup(env1)
            cleanup(env2)
        }
    }
}


def cleanup(env) {
    withEnv(env) {
        sh "./cleanup.py"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parallel` keyword can work inside a post condition as long as it is encapsulated inside a `script` block, as the `script` blocks is just a fallback to the scripted pipeline which will allow you to run parallel execution wherever you want.
The following should work fine:

```
 post {
    always{
        script {
            def environments = ['env1', 'env2', 'env3']
            parallel environments.collectEntries {
                ["Cleanup ${it}" : {
                    cleanup(it)
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}


def cleanup(env) {
    withEnv(env) {
        sh "./cleanup.py"
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to allocate an agent using the `node` keyword if the steps in the post section are required to run on a specific agent.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea in my opinion is to clean up after the fact, before you possibly lost the node to another job:

```
parallel {
    stage('env1') {
        agent { node { label "env1" }}
        steps {
            script {
                println "Inside env1"   
            }
        }
        post {
            cleanup { script { my_cleanup_func("env1") } }
        }
    }
    stage('env2') {
        agent { node { label "env2" }}
        steps {
            script {
                println "Inside env2"   
            }
        }
        post {
            cleanup { script { my_cleanup_func("env2") } }
        }
    }
...
def my_cleanup_func(String env) {
    // ...
}
```